# Intra-Process Communication in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipc

I want to know how can a child thread talk to parent thread in Objective C. I am spawning a thread from my main thread and want to intimate main thread about some action and keep continuing. How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want inter-process or intra-process communication? Your question doesn't really match up with its title.

Comment: The main thread is not necessarily parent thread. It is easy to get the main thread. I still didn't find any way to get parent thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you post a NSNotification in the child thread, the receiver will receive the notification and execute under `the same thread` as the sender. The apple document said that and marked as a note.
- The information between threads can be transfered by a shared memory, ex: a struct, primitive types (int, CGFloat, etc).
- The information between thread can be transfered by [threadDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003746) property of NSThread. I prefer to use this to register some status variables. For example, when scrolling, I will set following.

  ```
  NSMutableDictionary *dictInfo = [NSThread mainThread].threadDictionary;
  [dictInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithbool:YES] forKey:_kThreadPause];
  ```

  The worker thread will go to sleep when it see the _kThreadPause is set to YES.

  ```
  BOOL bPause = [[[NSThread mainThread].threadDictionary objectForKey:_kThreadPause] boolValue];
  if (bPause) [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
  ```
- As DavidNeiss said, you can use methods of NSObject to perform selector on main thread or child thread.

  If you have time, you can read [threading programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i).

Comment: Another option is to spawn and encapsulate thread via NSOperation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have the other thread run a selector back on the main thread and share info through an ivar.

```
-(void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the thread post an NSNotification that the main thread is listening for (observing) and pass information in the NSNotification's object.